# Possible to autorender in Ruby Espresso framework?

Tags: ruby

I really like the way Ramaze auto renders templates without you having to call a render function. Is it possible to have the same in Espresso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, i liked it too when were using Ramaze.

However, with Espresso, there are multiple reasons to NOT do this automatically.

Instead of listing them, i'll post a easy way of achieving this.

You simply need to set an `after` hook for controllers that will have autorender enabled.

You can set the hook inside each controller or for all at once when you build your app:

```
E.new do
  setup_controllers do
    after { response.body = [ render ] }
  end
  # ...
end
```

You can of course set it for specific controllers only:

```
E.new do
  setup_controllers do
    if self == Foo || self == Bar
      after { response.body = [ render ] }
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

as well as for specific actions:

```
E.new do
  setup_controllers do
    if self == Foo
      after(:index) { response.body = [ render ] }
    elsif self == Bar
      after(/blah/) { response.body = [ render ] }
    else
      after { response.body = [ render ] }
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

note: posting a bit hairy code for demonstration purposes, optimize it as required by your application.